# Heap size limit problem with Salesforce and DocuSign

Tags: salesforce, heap-memory, docusignapi

I am facing issue with Salesforce and DocuSign integration where SF limit 12mb presents problems for large files that need to be signed.

What would be best approach to work around this issue? My current idea is to somehow externalise flow. Use CometD to listen some (probably custom) event from SF and my app would then use GET REST call to fetch those files from SF. GET REST call to SFP supports up to 2GB. Once I have them plan is to put them in the envelope using DocuSign SDK. When the documents are signed I would retrieve them and store back to SF.

Where I struggle in this flow is the beginning and the end. What would trigger that event? Some custom LWC app? And where/how to put those files back to SF.

Comment: How large are your documewnts?

Comment: well at the point where file is bigger than 12mb does it make difference if it is 15mb or 200mb?

Comment: yes, it makes a different. 25M is the maximum allowed in a single API call